# About xpath in table java

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find the xpath of the  button(its an input for real) from the name of the person in the corresponding line.

the right "connection" button from the name.

I have tried several xpath may saucun do not click the button I want.

It Clicks on the first button of the whole table each time

I tried this:

```
*d.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(), 'TOTO')]/following-sibling::td/input"));
```

and

```
*d.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'TOTO')]/following-sibling::td/input"));
```

and

```
*d.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(), 'TOTO')]/following-sibling::td/input[type='submit']"));
```

and

```
*d.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(),'TOTO')]//td[5]/input"));
```

I enclose the table.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<tr>
        <td>FR1547</td>
        <td>CAILLOUX</td>
        <td>CHRISTIANE</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>UTILISATEUR</td>
        <td><input value="connection" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenCuid').value = 'FR1547'" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>US7784</td>
        <td>TOTO</td>
        <td>CHRISTINE</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>UTILISATEUR</td>
        <td><input value="connection" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenCuid').value = 'US7784'" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
```

Second button  :

```
<tr>
    <td>US4487</td>
    <td>PONT</td>
    <td>CHRISTIANE</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>UTILISATEUR, MANAGER</td>
    <td><input value="connection" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenCuid').value = 'US4487'" type="submit"></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share HTML code for connection button

Comment: @MarieJeanne If you are not able to click, What is an error it's giving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath And check with Debugger, Whether its locates correctly:

```
//input[contains(@onclick,'US4487')]
```

Comment: Both solutions work very well.
Thank you from the bottom of the heart guys

Comment: If you think answer has helped you to solve problem, please accept it and up vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this xpath :

```
//td[text()='TOTO']/parent::tr/child::input
```

Comment: when you inspect the page , how many entries are present in console bar with the respective xpath?

Comment: Both solutions work very well.
Thank you from the bottom of the heart guys

Comment: @MarieJeanne : glad that it worked, you can click on check mark which is just under the down vote button and beside my answer. Thank you !